# Django socialauth: what is the best fork?

Tags: django, openid, django-socialauth

i'm trying to install socialauth in my django application to have openid and facebook login, but it seems there are various versions of socialauth:

- [uswaretech](http://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth) which has a poor doc, a very bad template system
- [elfsternberg](http://github.com/elfsternberg/Django-Socialauth/tree/master/socialauth/) which is defended by [this](http://www.elfsternberg.com/2009/11/24/django-socialauth-component-now-with-some-elfin-goodness/) but was last updated nov09
- [agiliq](http://github.com/agiliq/Django-Socialauth) update one month ago but seems to have even more bugs... (though sternberg is part of the contributors)
- others which are even less transparent

what do you recommend?

Comment: @meder: i ended up using django socialregistration and for the moment it ok. I really lost a lot of time with socialauth (all versions) and i do not recommend it. Hope it helps

Comment: does that include gmail/yahoo like how SO has it? Or is it more limited?

Comment: @meder not like SO because, there is no nice buttons for each open-id providers but just a single login form wher you put you opendid. You are then free to create your own buttons with the logo (eg: google) where you specify the openid string (eg https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id) in an hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really dont suggest you socialauth, have some bugs, facebook connect doesn't work fine, i suggest you find a good app for oauth, openid and use django-facebookconnect or oficial python/javascript sdk facebook with opengraph

Comment: (and open source when you're finished)

Comment: The fact that django-facebookconnect can work with *existing* user accounts is key - with the other systems you end up with a tangle of duplicate users if they log in once normally, another time with FB, another time with Twitter. Chaos ensues.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you asked for socialauth, but I thought you can try using socialregistration found at: http://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration

It worked for me.